# ffmpeg add all audio tracks to video conversion (mkv)

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, mkv

I have a script that takes in input a video file (generally avi or mp4) and converts it to a "lower quality" mkv video optimized for web streaming.

The ffmpeg command I use is this one:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i file:"$input" -sn -codec:v:0 libx264 -force_key_frames expr:gte\(t,n_forced*5\) -vf "scale=trunc(min(max(iw\,ih*dar)\,1280)/2)*2:trunc(ow/dar/2)*2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset superfast -crf 23 -b:v 1680000 -maxrate 1680000 -bufsize 3360000 -vsync vfr -profile:v high -level 41 -map_metadata -1 -threads 8 -codec:a:0  libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 320000 -af "aresample=async=1" -y "$output"
```

The problem is that this command only includes the first audio track of my video. I have some dual language videos (italian and english) for which I want to include both languages.

Is there a simple ffmpeg command option that automatically includes all audio tracks found in a video?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `-map 0:a` to include all audio streams.

Comment: [NULL @ 0x3c905e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '0:a'
0:a: Invalid argument